# Add a count row for various columns at top of query results

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

Here is a sample of the data (TRAILER table)...

```
trailer_id  Zone        Status
2X0705       V2R 5M3    AVAIL
2X0706       V2R 5M3    AVAIL
2X0808       V2R 5M3    AVAIL
2X0817       V2R 5M3    AVAIL
3X1226       V2R 5M3    AVAIL
2X0777       V2R 5M3    DISP
2X0814       V2R 5M3    SPTLD
```

The query is super simple:

```
select trailer_id, zone, status 
from trailer
where zone = 'V2R 5M3'
group by zone, status, trailer_id
order by zone, status, trailer_id
```

Is there any way to add a count for each STATUS at the top of the query? Something like:

```
AVAIL = 5 | DISP = 1 | SPTLD = 1
```

to elaborate - on the top line of the results - is there a way to show count of where the trailer is in AVAIL (status) and DISP (status) and SPTLD (status)
or perhaps one line for each status

- AVAIL count
- SPTLD count
- DISP count

We are using  SQL Server 2019 if that helps.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Replace pictures with formatted text. Also your desired output is not clear. Are you wanting just a single row of output, or rather, your current output plus another row that looks nothing like your original output columns, or another column, or???? Add your desired output as formatted text to make this more clear.

Comment: which database system are you using and whuch version

Comment: Sounds like something that should be done in the application level.

Comment: A resultset cannot have different columns per row, it's not clear what you are expecting, add your expected results in tabular format please.

Comment: Like mentioned above, have the application level show what you want. It's in bad form to have total counts on top of other non-total data. Is it possible? Yes but ugly. Should you do it? No. If you're truly curious in seeing totals in your IDE, then run a separate query, or use a windows function to add a column to your existing query such as `count(*) over (partition by status) as stat_total_count`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GROUPING SETS` for this. The `GROUPING` function tells you if a column has been grouped for a particular row.

```sql
select
  trailer_id,
  zone,
  status,
  case when grouping(trailer_id) = 1 then count(case when status = 'AVAIL' then 1 end) end as AVAIL,
  case when grouping(trailer_id) = 1 then count(case when status = 'DISP'  then 1 end) end as DISP,
  case when grouping(trailer_id) = 1 then count(case when status = 'SPTLD' then 1 end) end as SPTLD
from trailer
where zone = 'V2R 5M3'
group by grouping sets (
    (zone, status, trailer_id),
    ()
)
order by
  grouping(trailer_id) desc,
  zone, status, trailer_id;
```

I would recommend though that you instead put this into your application level, as this type of query is often inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what the trailer_id is for in this query.
You should try `OVER()`

```
select status
    , count(zone) over (partition by status) as count
from trailer
where zone = 'V2R 5M3'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could acheive that using window function to count the number of rows for each `status`:

```
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY status) AS StatusCount
```

[**`DB_FIDDLE`**](https://dbfiddle.uk/P-iUVRhN)

Answer (score 0):

Using a **CTE** *Common Table Expression* for the StatusCounts

```
WITH StatusCounts AS (
    SELECT
        status,
        COUNT(*) AS StatusCount
    FROM
        TrailerStatus
    GROUP BY
        status
)
```

Joins this **CTE** to the table based on the `status` column:

```
SELECT
    t.trailer_id,
    t.zone,
    t.status,
    sc.StatusCount
FROM
    TrailerStatus t
JOIN
    StatusCounts sc ON t.status = sc.status
ORDER BY
    t.zone,
    t.status,
    t.trailer_id;
```

[***`DEMO`***](https://dbfiddle.uk/P-iUVRhN)